# Qt - Hiding window when the close button is hit

Tags: qt, user-interface, terminal, qmainwindow

I am trying to implement a terminal in my application. [image: Terminal]

Currently, `class Terminal` inherits from `QMainWindow`, and all of its contents are lost if the close button is triggered. This does not affect the main application though.

I want the contents to stay and be accessible by the rest of the application. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think you can handle the close event and ignore it, then minimize the window: define a `void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *evt)` function with `evt->ignore();`. Then call `setWindowState()` to toggle the `Qt::WindowMinimized` flag.. Unfortunately I don't have Qt installed right now to try it.

Comment: If the problem is that the application quits when the window is closed, call [`QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) with `false` as the parameter.

Comment: If you merely want to minimize the window instead of close it, dschulz's comment is the way to go.

Comment: @JonHarper I want the window to completely vanish, but the contents should stay there if I open the window again.

Comment: @HenryW. you should save your terminal content into local place such as settings/db/files in close event.

Comment: @HenryW. , how would you *open the window again*? do you mean by starting the application again?

Comment: @Mike The terminal is a part of the application (which is not in the screen shot). It is launched by triggering an action in the application.

Comment: See the [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) window attribute.